# CDHtmlDialog set focus on an Input field

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, msdn

I would like to have the focus on an Input field in my `CDHtmlDialog` box called using `doModal()`.

I created the following code:

```
CComPtr<IHTMLInputElement>  pincode;
GetElementInterface(_T("pincode"),
                    IID_IHTMLInputElement, (void **) &pincode);
if (pincode == NULL) {
    return;
}
pincode->select();
//set the focus
CComPtr<IHTMLElement2>  pincode2;
GetElementInterface(_T("pincode"),
                    IID_IHTMLElement2 , (void **) &pincode2);
if (pincode2 == NULL) {
    return;
}
pincode2->focus();
```

But when I run my application the focus is not set to the input field. The field is selected: the cursor is in it so at first sight we might think we can write in the input field, but when we write nothing happen in the field!

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do it using javascript in your html code?
something like `document.getElementById('pincode').focus();`, it may be a simple workaround.

I always prefer do UI related code directly in HTML using javascript, (I think `CDHtmlDialog` sometimes have kind of esoteric behavior).

my two cents

I hope this helps

Comment: It is a good idea, but it does the same thing than the code I used: the field seems to be selected, but the when we try to write something, nothing happen.

Comment: weird, as if the dialog itself does not have the focus?

Comment: It worked! A strange thing happened: when visual studio is launched, that's him who takes the focus, but I soon as i close it, my dialog box has the focus!
Thanks for your answer!